# Why does my regular navbar cover header while the collapsed one does not? (bootstrap/fullpage)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

I have some problems with my navbar covering my header instead of positioning below relative to the header height. When i use a smaller screen and the navbar goes over to collapse it positions below like it should, how come?

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(asdasdads-321-redigerad-2.jpg);
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-default {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(51, 51, 51, 0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <h1>header</h1>
  <p>asdf asdas dasdadf dgfsd sdf asf fsdfsdf sdfa sfasf df</p>
</header>

<nav class="navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-container">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-container">
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#firstPage" title="Ab knapp" id="Ab-logo">UPPDRAG</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="secondPage" id="filosofi"><a href="#secondPage">FILOSOFI</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="thirdPage" id="uppdrag"><a href="#thirdPage">UPPDRAG</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="4thpage" id="karriär"><a href="#4thpage">KARRIÄR</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="5thpage" id="academy"><a href="#5thpage">ACADEMY</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="lastPage" id="kontakt"><a href="#lastPage">KONTAKT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why using .header position fixed ?? it overlap by nav
    header {
      width: 100%;
     height: 100px;

```
    top: 0;
} use try this
```

Comment: well im trying to create a navbar that moves from relative to fixed on scrolling but i cant get the nav to position below header. it positions straight on the header now

Comment: you are trying to that nav comes first then header comes or vice versa ??

Comment: I want my header to push down my nav.

Comment: so remove the position fixed it comes down

Comment: well that was easy. How did i not see that! thank you!

Comment: @Grunter yes some time it happen when develop the code